# Como inserir dados em outra tabela a partir da chave estrangeira?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela no meu banco de dados chamada `imoveis` onde nela tenho algumas colunas, destacando-se `localizacao_fk` e `correspondencia_fk`, ambas chaves estrangeiras que fazem referência à tabela `enderecos`. O que eu quero saber é como inserir dados na tabela `imoveis` de tal forma que o povoamento das colunas `localizacao_fk` e `correspondencia_fk` automaticamente seja feito na tabela `enderecos`.

Uma visão geral do que pretendo fazer é a seguinte:

Tenho um formulário de cadastro onde, em determinado ponto, tenho campos de dois tipos de endereços a serem preenchidos: o primário (referente à coluna `localizacao_fk`) e o secundário (`correspondencia_fk`). Mas no banco, campos desse formulário como CEP, logradouro, bairro e cidade não estão na tabela `imoveis`, e sim em `enderecos`. Logo, o preenchimento de tais campos povoariam tanto `localizacao_fk` quanto `correspondencia_fk` (caso eu deseje fornecer esse endereço secundário).

Help!

Eis os prints das tabelas:

Tabela endereços:
<kbd>[image: tabela endereços]</kbd>

Tabela imóveis:
<kbd>[image: tabela imóveis]</kbd>

Comment: Poderia posta suas tabelas.

Comment: Já disponibilizei os links no post.

Answer (score 1):

vc tem que adicionar primeiro na tabela endereco pegar a id e adicionar esse id na imoveis.

no seu formulario tem os campos de endereço localização e correspondencia.

quando vc salvar o formulario,  primeiro salve a tabela endereco.
como poderao ser 2 endereços salve o primeiro guarde o id numa variavel depois o mesmo com o segundo.
finalize colocando os ids em imoveis

Comment: Localização e correspondência são chaves estrangeiras da tabela endereços.

Comment: Disponibilizei no post os links dos prints das tabelas.